# How to delay response in ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to delay the ajax success for 1 second in rails ajax . Can anyone suggest me how can i do this in general jquery ajax it is possible but when it comes to using rails ajax I am unable to find away to edit ajax response time . I have the following code for my rails ajax below .

```
 $(".feed-like-<%= @feed.id %>").html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/dislike' %>");
    $(".count-<%= @feed.id %>").html('<%= @feed_like_counter.like_count %> ');
```

How can I add this kind of query :

```
  // set your delay here, 2 seconds as an example...
                var my_delay = 2000;

                // call your ajax function when the document is ready...
                $(function() {
                    callAjax();
                });

                // function that processes your ajax calls...
                function callAjax() {
                    $.ajax({
                        // ajax parameters here...
                        // ...
                        success: function() {
                            setTimeout(callAjax, my_delay);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I know this doesn't answer your question, but in my experience, using delays and setTimeout is usually a way of covering up / poorly solving a different problem.

Comment: I am trying to create a like and dislike function but when I  click on ajax once it works great and after that it render a dislike partial but in between rendering a dislike partial it takes time but when I click fast 2 times it update the query so for this if I am able to  delay the event so that my query don't get updated

Comment: The right thing to do here is disable the button on click, submit ajax and wait until success fires to re-enable it. The delay is too arbitrary, and not a guaranteed way to prevent that scenario from happening.

Comment: disable good idea let me implement it how should I use bind method in rails can you please explain

Comment: Like I said, delays and settimeouts are usually cover-ups for other things. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular problem you can use the rails method disable_with you can use in your code like this :

```
 <%= link_to "like",{ :action => 'create', :controller => 'feed_likes', :feed_id => @feed, :user_id => current_user.id, :remote => true },data: { disable_with: "Processsing..." }, method: :post,class: "btn btn-primary"   %>
```